# Why is TortoiseSVN update trying to access 'C:\Windows\SERVIC~2\NETWOR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\svn-A2A11F74' when the working copy is on the other drive?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

we have multiple users working on SVN repository for several weeks without any issues. Suddenly many of them started to receive an error during SVN update:

[image: "Can't set position pointer in file 'C:\Windows\SERVIC~2\NETWOR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\svn-A2A11F74': There is not enough space on the disk."]

`"Can't set position pointer in file 'C:\Windows\SERVIC~2\NETWOR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\svn-A2A11F74': There is not enough space on the disk."` `svn-A2A11F74` is different for different users.

All the users have their working copies on the other drives than C: and all of them use TortoiseSVN client in the context of their own usernames/profiles, not a network service.

Sometimes the error shows immediately, sometimes after some files were transmitted.

Our current workaround is to delete the .svn directory and checkout from repository to the same local location so only .svn gets downloaded but this takes hours due to the size of repository and is not the solution to the root cause of the problem.

What causes TortoiseSVN to try accessing network service profile? How to resolve it?

Comment: Specify the version of your server and check its logs. Are there any errors in the server's log?

Comment: Indeed there was no space left on the servers' C: drive. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem was on the server that has no space left on its C: drive.

Answer (score 0):

Some service running with `NetworkService` built-in account cannot work properly because there is not enough space on drive C: (where this NetworkService has its Temp folder set up). Some services that are running with NetworkService account are:

Cryptographic Services
IPSec Policy Agent
Network Location Awareness
Remote Desktop Services

TortoiseSVN probably uses some of those services, and then the service fails. It could be even some anti-virus software.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. TortoiseSVN is not working as a service in the system. It looks like the client get the error from the server that was not related to the client system.

Comment: FYI: HTTP service of VisualSVN Server runs as Network Service by default.